# FirebaseUI in typescript and react-redux does not compile

Tags: typescript, firebase, asp.net-core, react-redux, firebaseui

I'm trying to use firebaseui to do a login in react-redux using typescript, as follows:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
import fire from '../FirebaseCreds';


export class FirebaseAuth {
    public Login() {
        var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    }
}
```

This causes a compile error or something (I just get an internal server error with no error output so not sure what's going on).

Error being:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error:
>   ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like you just need to pay more attention to the error messages here. Just from that one error message alone I can see that it's trying to run server-side rendering in NodeJS (NodeInvocationException, Prerendering) and it's failing because it's trying to use the 'window' object, and that only exists when you're in a browser.

So I'd imagine you've picked up a bootstrap app or existing system where it does server-side prerendering, added firebaseui to it and then when you run it it tries to execute loads of browser-only firebase code that tries to access the window object.

It isn't going to be possible to make firebaseui server side renderable so your best bet would be to only do this when in an actual browser, for example, in a componentDidMount method, get rid of server side rendering or use the auth api instead of the full web ui.